# Why does nobody care that Danielle and Ben hooked up?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost

In Lost, after season 3, everybody knows that Danielle is Alex's mother and Ben says he is his father. And everybody seems cool with it, but I am not? There is no hints or scenes in the show yet which shows any kind of connection between Danielle and Ben. Why did nobody ask Danielle how Ben is Ben the father?

As I remember she told them she was already pregnant when she came to the island and Ben was already on the island long ago. Then isn't it stupid for nobody to talk about it? Even if there is a secret/suspense lies in that part of story, why don't Jack, John, Kate or even Alex give a damn about Danielle and Ben hooking up 16 years ago?

**P.S.** I am currently on s04e08, so please try to use spoiler blocks if the answer requires spoilers.

Comment: Two comments: The story between Danielle and Ben is more complex and will be detailed in future episodes (Season 5). I don't think that the connection between Danielle and Ben is the most important issue of the people in LOST, maybe that's why they never questioned it.

Comment: It was mentioned repeatedly in the first two seasons that Alex was forcibly taken away from Danielle. So for me while watching this series (and before reaching the full explanation in later seasons), it was always more likely that Ben Linus, as a member of the Others who had kidnapped Alex, had simply "adopted" Alex as his daughter -- than that he was really her biological father.

Answer (score 7):

I don't want to spoil anything for you so I'll answer your question but I'm putting it in spoiler tags for your benefit. At the rate you seem to be going through episodes though I think you have probably either already seen some of these details and just missed it or will see them soon. There are actually two episodes in season 5 which show flashbacks explaining exactly how Ben is Alex's father.

> Answer: He isn't Alex's literal biological father. He kidnapped Alex from a younger Danielle and raised her as his daughter among The Others. 
> From the [Lostpedia page for Alex](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Rousseau)-- When Alex was one week old, Benjamin Linus crept into Danielle's tent under the orders to kill her. However Ben changed his mind on the sight of Alex. Ben took baby Alex back to the Others' camp. Charles Widmore, leader of the Others at the time, insisted that he kill the child, to which Ben inquired if it was "the will of Jacob". Ben asked Charles to kill her himself, and he looked very put off by the suggestion, declining to do so. Alex was raised by Ben as one of the Others, and she was told that her mother was dead.

Comment: can you tell which two episodes of season 5... I have started season 5.. currently on second episode

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth The episodes are "This Place is Death" and "Dead is Dead".

Answer (score 7):

Since you are now in season 5, let me just remind you what Ben said in the season 4 episode "The Shape of Things to Come": "She's not my daughter.  I stole her from an insane woman.  She means nothing to me."  Now granted, he's being insincere in part of that statement, but let me also remind you that in the season 4 premiere, when Ben talks to Danielle Rousseau and says the phrase "my daughter", she elbows him and says "She's not your daughter."

Here's the full answer with spoilers:

> The season 5 episode "This Place is Death" shows that Rousseau's boyfriend Robert is Alex's father.  And the season 5 episode "Dead is Dead" shows Ben kidnapping Alex from Rousseau.